# psql: SELECT * ... except one column

Tags: postgresql, psql

I search for a simple way to select all columns except one in psql.

With `psql` I mean the interactive command line.

I would be happy with a tool that expands to `*` to a list of quoted column names. Then I could remove the column to remove by hand.

My question is just about the interactive usage of psql. It is not a duplicate of questions of people unhappy with the sql standard and who want to execute something like "select *-foo".

Comment: There isn't one, sorry. You can query `information_schema` via a pl/pgsql function to generate a list pretty easily, but that way it'd be two queries.

Comment: Most GUI tools can do that. But if you want to (or have to) stick to the command line, maybe this will help: https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would like to accept your "answer". Could you please post an answer and explain the usage of the pgcli tool solving the question.

Comment: except which column? the last one? the first one? Or random one?

Comment: @ChengchengPei the column name could be `foo_col` :-)

Comment: Why not just do DESC on your table, cut/paste the column list and then eliminate the one you want? That's the easiest I think. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341192/return-all-the-columns-in-a-mysql-table-in-a-string-format can help...

Comment: @ChengchengPei: there is no `desc` command in `psql`

Comment: Sorry for that. But there should be similar syntax in psql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the list of columns in default order, without the bad column:

```
SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ' ORDER BY attnum)
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'myschema.mytable'::regclass
AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
AND    attnum > 0        -- no system columns
AND    attname <> 'bad_column'  -- case sensitive!
```

Or just `WHERE  attrelid = 'mytable'::regclass` if you trust the [search path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) to resolve to the right schema.

[`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) adds double-quotes where necessary.

I asked the [same question in 2007 on pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/1180483885.536572.84550@q69g2000hsb.googlegroups.com#1180483885.536572.84550@q69g2000hsb.googlegroups.com). It was Postgres 8.2 back then. Sweet memories ...

Related:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)

Comment: It sounds like a to-do item, to add a backslash command to psql which will emit a string which is a list of all the columns for a table, appropriately quoted.  And you could have it omit any columns which were included as extra arguments to the command.  So hypothetically `\dq thetable bad_column`.

Comment: @jjanes: I am not sure it can generate enough demand to convince core developers to allocate the free letter `q` for the task. Maybe a general option to the whole family of `\d` commands to show a bare list of concatenated names? Like `\d- tbl` (mnemonic: the opposite of `\d+`, which shows *more* details). This would allow to get basically *any* bare list of objects. Tables in a schema: `\dt- public.*`, functions starting with "f_foo": `\df- f_foo*` etc. - or columns in a table: `\d- mytbl`. Similar to what the shell command `ls` does ...

Comment: I give you the bounty. But something built-in into psql would be really a nice feature. Thank you Erwin :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found what you are looking for but I have not tested it myself.

There is a software called SequelPro that would allow you to select the fields from a given table but its only for MySQL. Please read from the below from somewhere in the middle of the page:

> http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/Working_with_Query_Favorites

There is another software called PSequel which only runs on Mac and it claims it is of type SequelPro built for Postgres:

> http://www.psequel.com/

Hope this helps.