# Duplicate row with Primary Key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, dynamic-sql, default-value

Assume I have a table as follows named `people`, where `id` is a Primary Key:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+
|  id       |  fname  |  lname  |
| (integer) | (text)  | (text)  |
+===========+=========+=========+
|  1        | Daniel  | Edwards |
|  2        | Fred    | Holt    |
|  3        | Henry   | Smith   |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

I'm trying to write a row duplication query which is robust enough to account for schema changes to the table. Any time I add a column to the table, I don't want to have to go back and modify the duplication query.

I know I can do this, which will duplicate record id 2 and give the duplicated record a new id:

```
INSERT INTO people (fname, lname) SELECT fname, lname FROM people WHERE id = 2;
```

However if I add an `age` column, I'll need to modify the query to also account for the age column.

Obviously I can't do the following, because it will also duplicate the primary key, resulting in a `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` -- And, I don't want them to share the same id anyway:

```
INSERT INTO people SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = 2
```

With that said, what would be a reasonable approach to solving this challenge? I would prefer to stay away from stored procedures, but I'm not 100% against them, I suppose ...

Comment: Aside: maybe you should use a different example, since `age` is kind of an anti-pattern for a column. (One should rather store the `birthday`.)

Comment: Great question, thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Simple with `hstore`

If you have the additional module `hstore` installed ([instructions in link below](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82044/3684)), there is a **surprisingly simple** way to replace the value(s) of individual field(s) without knowing anything about other columns:

Basic example: duplicate the row with `id = 2` but replace `2` with `3`:

```
INSERT INTO people
SELECT (p #= hstore('id', '3')).* FROM people p WHERE id = 2;
```

Details:

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782641/939860)
- [Assign to NEW by key in a Postgres trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82039/assign-to-new-by-key-in-a-postgres-trigger/82044#82044)

***Assuming*** (since it's not defined in the question) that `people.id` is a **`serial`** column with an attached sequence, you'll want the next value from the sequence. We can determine the sequence name with `pg_get_serial_sequence()`. Details:

- [PostgreSQL SELECT primary key as "serial" or "bigserial"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90555/postgresql-select-primary-key-as-serial-or-bigserial/90567#90567)

Or you can just hard-code the sequence name if it's not going to change.
We *would* have this query:

```
INSERT INTO people
SELECT (p #= hstore('id', nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('people', 'id'))::text)).*
FROM people p WHERE id = 2;
```

Which *works*, but suffers from a weakness in the Postgres query planner: The expression is evaluated separately for every single column in the row, wasting sequence numbers and performance. To avoid this, move the expression into a subqery and decompose the row *once* only:

```
INSERT INTO people
SELECT (p1).*
FROM  (
   SELECT p #= hstore('id', nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('people', 'id'))::text) AS p1
   FROM   people p WHERE id = 2
   ) sub;
```

Probably fastest for a single (or few) row(s) at once.

#### json / jsonb

If you don't have `hstore` installed and can't install additional modules, you can do a similar trick with `json_populate_record()` or `jsonb_populate_record()`<strike>, but that capability is undocumented and may be unreliable</strike>. **Update:** The feature is also documented since Postgres 13. See:

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28673097/939860)

#### Transient temporary table

Another simple solution would be to use a transient temporary like this:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE people_tmp ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE people_tmp SET id = nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('people', 'id'));
INSERT INTO people TABLE people_tmp;
COMMIT;
```

I added `ON COMMIT DROP` to drop the table automatically at the end of the transaction. Consequently, I also wrapped the operation into a transaction of its own. Neither is strictly necessary.

This offers a wide range of additional options - you can do anything with the row before inserting, but it's going to be a bit slower due to the overhead of creating and dropping a temp table.

This solution works for a single row or for ***any number of rows at once***. Each row gets a new default value from the sequence automatically.

Using the [short (SQL standard) notation `TABLE people`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276023/939860).

#### Dynamic SQL

For *many* rows at once, dynamic SQL is going to be fastest. Concatenate the columns from the system table `pg_attribute` or from the information schema and execute it dynamically in a `DO` statement or write a function for repeated use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_row_copy(_tbl regclass, _id int, OUT row_ct int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT format('INSERT INTO %1$s(%2$s) SELECT %2$s FROM %1$s WHERE id = $1',
                    _tbl, string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', '))
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
      AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    attnum > 0        -- no system columns
      AND    attname <> 'id'   -- exclude id column
      )
   USING _id;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;  -- directly assign OUT parameter
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_row_copy('people', 9);
```

Works for any table with an integer column named `id`. You could easily make the column name dynamic, too ...

Maybe not your first choice since you wanted to `stay away from stored procedures`, but then again, it's [not a "stored procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896307/939860) anyway ...

Related:

- [psql: SELECT * ... except one column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114760/psql-select-except-one-column/115315#115315)
- [List all columns for a specified table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table/22420#22420)

#### Advanced solution

A `serial` column is a special case. If you want to fill more or all columns with their respective default values, it gets more sophisticated. Consider this related answer:

- [Generate DEFAULT values in a CTE UPSERT using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797357/939860)

Comment: `hstore` approach works great, however I think I will be playing around with the `jsonb` approach as I'm already heavily relying on it. Thanks much for the great write up, Erwin!

Comment: The transient temporary table worked really well for me where I needed to copy a block of records while changing another field.  `... WHERE fieldA=1 ... SET ... fieldA=2 ...`

Comment: Master Erwin, a huge thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `trigger` on insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER name BEFORE INSERT
```

In this trigger you make the ID NULL. When the trigger is finished the insert is done and Postgres will provide an ID. I assume that you have defined the ID as `DEFAULT NEXTVAL('A_SEQUENCE'::REGCLASS)`.

Comment: This will work, but it's quite a "Sneaky" solution that I think would end up causing problems in the long run.  I, personally, would avoid doing this if at all possible....  If he DOES choose to do this, I hope he would FIRST do a SELECT inside the trigger to see if the supplied ID existed .. if it did, then, and only then, set the NEW.id to NULL..

Comment: He can do that but if you choose to use a `NEXTVAL('A_SEQUENCE'::REGCLASS)` that you never provide an ID yourself for a new entry.

Comment: That depends on how code and/or external libraries in your code will use the database.  Some may manually query the SEQ.NEXTVAL and then send the generated ID in an INSERT statement.. I just wouldn't trust that the table/sequence/trigger trio would end up behaving "as expected" all the time.  Thus my first comment.

Answer (score -2):

Dynamic SQL Work great, I am looking for this since few years,

if you have more than one excluded column, try simply,

```
AND    attname <> 'id'   -- exclude id column
AND    attname <> 'second_col_name'   -- exclude second_col_name
```