# Is there a way to clone a row in a "maintainable" way (with PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I often have to clone rows in my applications so I do it the long way :

```
INSERT INTO mytable (a, b, c)
SELECT a,b,c FROM mytable WHERE id=12;
```

(id is declared as a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, 12 being the row to clone).

The thing is, when I add new fields to `mytable` I must remember to update the clone functions to also clone those new fields.

I would like to clone rows in a more *maintainable* way. Something like :

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT *, id:DEFAULT FROM mytable WHERE id=12;
```

As I write it, I also think it would be nice to clone *detail* rows : if I have a detail/child table declared with referential integrity like this :

```
CREATE TABLE mychild (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  parentid int REFERENCES mytable(id),
  a text
);
```

I could clone mytable and all childs in one command rather than :

1. clone mytable (the long way)
2. get the new `id`
3. clone all `mychild`, setting `parentid` to the new `id`

Is there anything in PostgreSQL (or extensions) that could help dealing with these cases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the additional module **`hstore`** installed, there is a very simple way to replace the value(s) of individual field(s) without knowing anything about other columns:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT (t1).*  -- note the parentheses
FROM  (
   SELECT t #= hstore('id', nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mytable', 'id'))::text) AS t1
   FROM   mytable t
   WHERE  id = 12
   ) sub;
```

All columns are cast to `text` and back in the process.

Closely related answer with **detailed explanation** and more (possibly a bit faster) alternatives:

- [Duplicate row with Primary Key in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/duplicate-row-with-primary-key-in-postgresql/122144#122144)

#### Clone parent row and all its children

That's more tricky. But based on the above, plus using a data-modifying CTE, there is a very elegant solution:

```
WITH ins_parent AS (
   INSERT INTO mytable
   SELECT (p).*  -- note the parentheses
   FROM  (
      SELECT t #= hstore('id', nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mytable', 'id'))::text) AS p
      FROM   mytable t
      WHERE  id = 2
      ) sub
   RETURNING id
   )
INSERT INTO mychild
SELECT (c).*
FROM  (
   SELECT t #= hstore('id', nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mychild', 'id'))::text)
            #= hstore('parentid', (SELECT id::text FROM ins_parent)) AS c
   FROM   mychild t
   WHERE  parentid = 2
   ) sub;
```

This uses the *new* `parentid` for all copies in the child table and assigns new serial values to the `id` column.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is completely derived from the one by Erwin. It clones a parent row and all its children using `jsonb` instead of `hstore` with a single query without knowing the name of the fields except the name of the primary key field.

```
WITH ins_parent AS (
  INSERT INTO mytable
  SELECT *
  FROM jsonb_populate_record(null::mytable, (
    SELECT
      row_to_json(t)::jsonb ||
      (
        '{"id": "'||nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mytable', 'id'))::text||'"}'
      )::jsonb as p
    FROM   mytable t
    WHERE  id = 2
  ))
  RETURNING id
)
  INSERT INTO mychild
  SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(null::mychild, t.c)).*
  FROM (
    SELECT
      row_to_json(sub)::jsonb ||
      (
        '{"id": "'    ||nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mychild', 'id'))::text||'",
         "parentid":"'||(SELECT id::text FROM ins_parent)||'"}'
      )::jsonb as c
    FROM   mychild sub
    WHERE  parentid = 2
  ) t
```