# INSERT duplicate rows for multiple, cascading 1:M child tables

Tags: postgresql, insert, cte

Imagine multiple parent-child tables with 1:M relationships. I would like to "cascade"-insert duplicate rows based on root parent table row selection.
Each table has `IDENTITY` primary key and each child table has FK to its parent ID (one level up).

#### The goal

Given root parent table ID, insert duplicate rows for it and all of its children.

I tried "cascading"-insert CTEs, but ran into issues where `RETURNING` is limited to return only inserted data, while I need extra information to connect the next `INSERT`.

I was able to accomplish this by adding an extra column (`copied_from_id`).

#### My question

Is there a way to accomplish the same **without extra column**?

I did see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148967) by @Erwin Brandstetter but his example only has 1 parent and child and I was not sure how to extend this to multiple levels

#### Example

Here is example DDL and DML to illustrate the issue

- lvl_one - top most, root, parent table
- lvl_two - child table of lvl_one (1:M)
- lvl_three - child table of lvl_two (1:M)

#### Setup

```
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lvl_one,lvl_two,lvl_three CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.lvl_one (
    id      bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name    text,
    CONSTRAINT lvl_one_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.lvl_two (
    id          bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    lvl_one_id  bigint NOT NULL,    
    name        text,
    CONSTRAINT lvl_two_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT lvl_two_lvl_one_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (lvl_one_id)
        REFERENCES public.lvl_one (id) 
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.lvl_three (
    id          bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    lvl_two_id  bigint NOT NULL,    
    name        text,
    CONSTRAINT lvl_three_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT lvl_three_lvl_two_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (lvl_two_id)
        REFERENCES public.lvl_two (id) 
);
```

#### Initial data

```
-- initial data
INSERT INTO lvl_one(name)               VALUES ('Honda'),   ('Ford'),       ('Toyota');
INSERT INTO lvl_two(lvl_one_id, name)   VALUES (1,'Civic'), (1,'Passport'), (3,'Prius');
INSERT INTO lvl_three(lvl_two_id, name) VALUES (1,'door'),  (1,'window'),   (3,'trunk');


SELECT * FROM lvl_one ORDER BY id;
-- id, name
--  1, "Honda"
--  2. "Ford"
--  3, "Toyota"

SELECT * FROM lvl_two ORDER BY id;
-- id, lvl_one_id, name
--  1, 1,   "Civic"
--  2, 1,   "Passport"
--  3, 3,   "Prius"

SELECT * FROM lvl_three ORDER BY id;
-- id, lvl_two_id,  name
--  1, 1,   "door"
--  2, 1,   "window"
--  3, 3,   "trunk"

SELECT 
  one.id AS one_id, one.name AS one_name
, two.id AS two_id, two.name AS two_name
, three.id AS three_id, three.name AS three_name
FROM lvl_one AS one 
LEFT OUTER JOIN lvl_two AS two ON one.id = two.lvl_one_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN lvl_three AS three ON two.id = three.lvl_two_id
ORDER BY one.id, two.id, three.id;
--1 "Honda"     1       "Civic"     1       "door"
--1 "Honda"     1       "Civic"     2       "window"
--1 "Honda"     2       "Passport"  NULL    NULL        
--2 "Ford"      NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL            
--3 "Toyota"    3       "Prius"     3       "trunk"
```

#### Solution (with adding extra column)

```
ALTER TABLE lvl_one   ADD COLUMN copied_from_id bigint;
ALTER TABLE lvl_two   ADD COLUMN copied_from_id bigint;
ALTER TABLE lvl_three ADD COLUMN copied_from_id bigint;


-- copy row id=1 from lvl_one and all its child tables
WITH source_one AS (
    SELECT id,name 
    FROM lvl_one 
    WHERE id=1
)
, copy_one AS (
    INSERT INTO lvl_one(name,copied_from_id)
    SELECT name,id AS copied_from_id
    FROM source_one
    RETURNING id AS new_one_id, copied_from_id
)
, copy_two AS (
    INSERT INTO lvl_two(lvl_one_id,name,copied_from_id)
    SELECT new_one_id, lvl_two.name,lvl_two.id AS copied_from_id
    FROM copy_one 
    INNER JOIN lvl_one ON lvl_one.id = copy_one.copied_from_id
    INNER JOIN lvl_two ON lvl_two.lvl_one_id = lvl_one.id
    RETURNING id AS new_two_id, copied_from_id
)
, copy_three AS (
    INSERT INTO lvl_three(lvl_two_id,name,copied_from_id)
    SELECT new_two_id, lvl_three.name, lvl_three.id AS copied_from_id
    FROM copy_two
    INNER JOIN lvl_two ON lvl_two.id = copy_two.copied_from_id
    INNER JOIN  lvl_three ON lvl_three.lvl_two_id = lvl_two.id
    RETURNING id AS new_three_id, copied_from_id
)
SELECT * FROM copy_one, copy_two, copy_three;
```

#### Expected results of duplicating `lvl_one.id=1`

Following rows will be created in all 3 tables as a result of "duplicating" `lvl_one.id=1` row.

```
-- lvl_one
-- 4,Honda,1

-- lvl_two
--4,4,Civic,1
--5,4,Passport,2

-- lvl_three
--4,4,door,1
--5,4,window,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `RETURNING` clause of an `INSERT` can only work with columns from the inserted row. Columns added by a `FROM` clause are invisible there.

See:

- [RETURNING causes error: missing FROM-clause entry for table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67154373/939860)

To work around this limitation, I suggest to `SELECT` before each `INSERT`, and generate prospective new serial IDs in advance with [**`nextval()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html). Then you have each old and new ID in the same row to make necessary connections.

An minor additional complication for this approach is that you have `IDENTITY` columns with `GENERATE ALWAYS`. So we need [`OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) for `INSERT` to write to those columns anyway. (Or you create your `IDENTITY` columns with `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`):

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO lvl_one(name)
   SELECT name
   FROM   lvl_one
   WHERE  id = 1  --  $1 here
   RETURNING id AS new_parent_id, name   -- just the one
   )
, sel2 AS (
   SELECT ins1.new_parent_id, t2.id, t2.name, nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('lvl_two', 'id')) AS new_id
   FROM   ins1
   JOIN   lvl_two t2 ON t2.lvl_one_id = 1   --  and $1 here
   )
, ins2 AS (
   INSERT INTO lvl_two(id, lvl_one_id, name) OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE 
   SELECT new_id, new_parent_id, name
   FROM   sel2
   )
, sel3 AS (
   SELECT sel2.new_id AS new_parent_id, t3.id, t3.name, nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('lvl_three', 'id')) AS new_id
   FROM   sel2
   JOIN   lvl_three t3 ON t3.lvl_two_id = sel2.id  -- old parent ID
   )
, ins3 AS (
   INSERT INTO lvl_three(id, lvl_two_id, name) OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE 
   SELECT new_id, new_parent_id, name
   FROM   sel3
   )
SELECT ins1.new_parent_id AS lvl1_id, ins1.name AS lvl1_name
     , sel2.new_id AS lvl2_id, sel2.name AS lvl2_name
     , sel3.new_id AS lvl3_id, sel3.name AS lvl3_name
FROM   ins1 
LEFT   JOIN sel2 USING (new_parent_id)
LEFT   JOIN sel3 ON sel3.new_parent_id = sel2.new_id
ORDER  BY lvl1_id, lvl2_id, lvl3_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=31a0d80429137ab078de804dfdaafc78)*

Performance should be pretty similar. The main benefit is that we need no additional table columns as requested.

The first `INSERT` is simple because it can only affect a single row by definition, so I didn't add another `SELECT` there. The following steps follow the same pattern and can descend as many levels as you need.

Also note that the outer `SELECT` in your original solution would produce incorrect results (not affecting actually inserted rows):

```
...
SELECT * FROM copy_one, copy_two, copy_three;
```

`CROSS JOIN` between the tables would combine rows that shouldn't be combined and exclude rows that shouldn't be excluded.

Comment: thanks @Erwin! The last SELECT was just there to complete the CTE "cascade". I needed to put something there just to illustrate the problem. But thanks for pointing the CROSS JOIN issue!