# Count NULL values per row

Tags: postgresql, null, postgresql-9.6, isnull

I would like to count the number of null's present per row in a table without enumerating column names. For example:

```
WITH t as (VALUES
  (NULL ,'hi',2,NULL,'null'),
  ('' ,'hi',2,3,'test'),
  (NULL ,'hi',2,3,'null')
)
SELECT countnulls(t)
FROM t;
```

Would result in:

```
numnulls
2
0
1
```

The closest I can get is with the following hack of `row_to_json()`:

```
select 
(CHAR_LENGTH(row_to_json(t)::text)
 - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(row_to_json(t)::text, 'null', '')))/4 from t;
```

Which is... quite the hack (not in a good way). It works, sort of, but it counts the string 'null' as a NULL when it is present in the actual data or in the column names. So it is incorrect in the above case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### 1. You know the column names

For Postgres **9.6** or later, use [**`num_nulls()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE)

```
SELECT id, num_nulls(a,b,c,d,e)
FROM   tbl;
```

Returns your desired result exactly, for any mix of data types.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE)

> `num_nulls(VARIADIC "any")` ...  returns the number of null arguments

For Postgres **9.5** or older, convert to `text[]`, [**`array_remove(arr, null)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and use the remaining array length for an exact count:

```
SELECT 5 - cardinality(array_remove(ARRAY[a::text,b::text,c::text,d::text,e::text], null))
FROM   tbl;
```

Any type can be cast to `text`. The cast is redundant for `text` columns, of course.

`array_remove()` requires Postgres 9.3 or later.
`cardinality()` requires Postgres 9.4 or later. Substitute with `array_length(arr, 1)` in older versions.

#### 2. You don't know column names, but Postgres does

When building on actual tables (or other registered objects like a view or a materialized view), we can retrieve column names from the system catalog [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) to fully automate with dynamic SQL. Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_num_nulls(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS SETOF int
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
      'SELECT num_nulls(%s) FROM %s'
    , (SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ')  -- column list
       FROM   pg_attribute
       WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
       AND    NOT attisdropped    -- no dropped (dead) columns
       AND    attnum > 0)         -- no system columns
    , _tbl
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_num_nulls('myschema.tbl');
```

Returns the count for for each row in current physical order. Nothing else, to be absolutely generic.

Related:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)
- [psql: SELECT * ... except one column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114760/psql-select-except-one-column/115315#115315)

We *could* also pass each row to return a single count for it using a polymorphic function. Related:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/939860)

#### 3. You don't know anything: anonymous records

In the unlikely event that column names are unknown even to Postgres (like from a `VALUES` expression in your example), convert to a document type (`json`, `jsonb`, `xml`, `hstore`) to get a handle, like demonstrated by ypercube (comment deleted by now) and [Evan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205887/count-null-values-per-row/205899#comment401967_205891).

But anonymous records do not have primary keys or any other ***unique*** attribute per definition. Count *within* each `LATERAL` subquery to defend against false aggregates. Demo with **`jsonb`**:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   VALUES
      (NULL ,'hi',2,NULL,'null')
    , (NULL ,'hi',2,NULL,'null')       -- duplicate row !!!
    , ('' ,'hi',2,3,'test')
    , (NULL ,'hi',2,3,'null')
   ) t                                 -- column names unknown
, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE j.value = jsonb 'null') AS num_nulls
   FROM   jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t)) j
   ) c;
```

Or with **`json`**: probably a bit faster because the conversion is cheaper.
Demonstrating 3 different ways:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   VALUES
      (NULL ,'hi',2,NULL,'null')
    , (NULL ,'hi',2,NULL,'null')
    , ('' ,'hi',2,3,'test')
    , (NULL ,'hi',2,3,'null')
   ) t   -- column names unknown
, to_json(t) j
, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE j1.value::text = 'null') AS num_nulls1
   FROM   json_each(to_json(t)) j1
   ) c1
, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE j->>k IS NULL) AS num_nulls2
   FROM   json_object_keys(j) k
   ) c2
, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) - count(j->>k ) AS num_nulls3
   FROM   json_object_keys(j) k
   ) c3;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=95d81b5008973253783d50ca1ca86eb8)*

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using the [jsonb features](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), but this is a really horrible idea.

```
SELECT t,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE jsonb_typeof(jrow->key) = 'null')
FROM ( VALUES
  (NULL ,'hi',2,NULL,'null'),
  ('' ,'hi',2,3,'test'),
  (NULL ,'hi',2,3,'null')
) AS t(a,b,c,d,e)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL to_jsonb(t) AS j1(jrow)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_object_keys(jrow) AS j2(key)
GROUP BY t;
        t         | count 
------------------+-------
 ("",hi,2,3,test) |     0
 (,hi,2,3,null)   |     1
 (,hi,2,,null)    |     2
(3 rows)
```

You could also expand it run it all in a `case` statement inside a `sum()` which would be fast,

```
SELECT t,
SUM(
  CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + 
  CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN e IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)
FROM ( VALUES
  (NULL ,'hi',2,NULL,'null'),
  ('' ,'hi',2,3,'test'),
  (NULL ,'hi',2,3,'null')
) AS t(a,b,c,d,e)
GROUP BY t;
        t         | sum 
------------------+-----
 ("",hi,2,3,test) |   0
 (,hi,2,3,null)   |   1
 (,hi,2,,null)    |   2
(3 rows)
```

Comment: `GROUP BY t` folds duplicate rows, though - generating false counts.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the `count FILTER where` pattern!