# Get absolute number and percentage of NULL values for each column of each table in a given schema

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, statistics

I'd like to extract some basic statistics about how tables are populated in a given PostgreSQL 16 schema, such as the absolute number and percentage of null values for each column in all tables in that schema.

Currently, I'm fetching/computing those values using Python/psycopg2, but I'm wondering if I can store some kind of function inside PostgreSQL itself that I can call each time I want to grab those statistics?

Comment: `COUNT(someColumn)` tells you how many non-nulls, so `COUNT(*) - COUNT(someColumn)` tells you how many nulls, and `(COUNT(*) - COUNT(someColumn)) * 100.0 / COUNT(*)` tells you the percentage. What exactly is your question? Do you know which tables and columns you want, or is it dynamic?

Comment: If approximate results are ok, you could query `pg_stats`.

Comment: That could be an idea indeed, but what exactly do you mean by "approximate"?

Comment: @s.k: `pg_stats` has statistics computed from a random sample, not exact counts.

Comment: Naive question: is it then possible to purposefully compute the same statistics on the entire dataset?

Comment: @s.k. Naive answer: Sure. For your question you then arrive at my answer. If estimates from `pg_stats` are good enough, use those. If the difference between *"0 %"* and *"almost 0 %"* matters, you need the exact count. But if you have concurrent write access, even an exact count may be dead on arrival. (Reposted to fix intrusive typos.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the absolute number and percentage of null values for each column in all tables

##### Test setup

```
CREATE TABLE test (col1 int, col2 text, col3 date);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (1, 'text', '2024-1-1')
, (2, 'text', null)
, (3, null  , null)
, (4, 'text', null)
, (5, null  , null)
;
```

#### Simple, naive, repetitive & slow

Basically, you want this kind of output for all columns of any give table:

```
SELECT 'col1' AS column
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE col1 IS NULL) AS has_null
     , round(count(*) FILTER (WHERE col1 IS NULL) / (count(*) / 100.0)) AS pct_null
FROM   test t

UNION ALL
SELECT 'col2' AS column
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE col2 IS NULL) AS has_null
     , round(count(*) FILTER (WHERE col2 IS NULL) / (count(*) / 100.0)) AS pct_null
FROM   test t

UNION ALL
SELECT 'col3' AS column
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE col3 IS NULL) AS has_null
     , round(count(*) FILTER (WHERE col3 IS NULL) / (count(*) / 100.0)) AS pct_null
FROM   test t;
```

| column | has_null | pct_null |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col1 | 0 | 0 |
| col2 | 2 | 40 |
| col3 | 4 | 80 |

#### Smart, but not dynamic, yet

Besides being much faster, this adds more data and defends against division by zero:

```
SELECT c.col AS column
     , c.null_ct AS has_null
     , round(c.null_ct / ct_div) AS pct_null
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
        , NULLIF(count(*), 0) / 100.0 AS ct_div
        , '{"* (total_row_count)","* (rows_with_any_null)",col1,col2,col3}'::text[] AS cols   
        , ARRAY [count(*)
               , count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT (t.*) IS NOT NULL)
               , count(*) FILTER (WHERE col1 IS NULL)
               , count(*) FILTER (WHERE col2 IS NULL)
               , count(*) FILTER (WHERE col3 IS NULL)
                 -- more?
                ] AS nulls
   FROM   test t
   ) sub, unnest(cols, nulls) AS c(col, null_ct);
```

| column_name | has_null | pct_null |
| --- | --- | --- |
| * (total_row_count) | 5 | 100 |
| * (rows_with_any_null) | 4 | 80 |
| col1 | 0 | 0 |
| col2 | 2 | 40 |
| col3 | 4 | 80 |

About `WHERE NOT (t.*) IS NOT NULL`:

- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21026085/939860)

Related:

- [Optimize query for columns with distinct values per ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78031601/939860)

### Full automation

What you really want: a fully automated function executing a dynamic query. With bells and whistles, and optimized performance. Also defends against possible SQL injection properly.

The function takes one or two arguments:

1. `_tbl regclass` ... Table name as (optinally schema-qalified) string literal or as OID type `regclass`
2. `_show_table_stats bool` ... Show additional table stats? Optional, default `false`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_null_ratio(_tbl regclass, _show_table_stats bool = false)
  RETURNS TABLE(column_name text, has_null bigint, pct_null numeric)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _cols text[];
   _nulls_sql text;
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _cols, _sql
        CASE WHEN _show_table_stats
               THEN '{* (total_row_count), * (rows_with_any_null)}'::text[] || array_agg(col)
               ELSE array_agg(col)
           END  -- AS cols
        , format(
/* dynamic query string */
$q$SELECT c.col  -- AS column
     , c.null_ct  -- AS has_null
     , round(c.null_ct / ct_div)  -- AS pct_null
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
        , NULLIF(count(*), 0) / 100.0 AS ct_div
        , $1 AS cols   
        , %1$s AS nulls
   FROM   %2$s t
   ) sub, unnest(cols, nulls) AS c(col, null_ct)$q$
/* dynamic query string */
               , CASE WHEN _show_table_stats
                      THEN 'ARRAY [count(*), count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT (t.*) IS NOT NULL), '
                      ELSE 'ARRAY [' END
              || string_agg('count(*) FILTER (WHERE ' || a.col || ' IS NULL)', ', ') || ']'  -- %1$s 
               , _tbl                                                                        -- %2$s 
                )  -- AS sql
   FROM  (
      SELECT a.attrelid, quote_ident(a.attname) AS col
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
      WHERE  a.attrelid = _tbl
      AND    NOT a.attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    a.attnum > 0        -- no system columns
      ORDER  BY a.attnum
      ) a;

   -- RAISE NOTICE E'%\n%', _sql, _cols;  -- debug?
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _sql
   USING _cols;
END
$func$;
```

Example calls:

```
SELECT * FROM f_null_ratio('public.test'::regclass);
SELECT * FROM f_null_ratio('test');
SELECT * FROM f_null_ratio('_tbl => public.test', _show_table_stats => true);
SELECT * FROM f_null_ratio('test', true);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qdVmXkVx)

Now you just call this function for every table of interest.
You need to know your way around PL/pgSQL to handle this properly.

About the use of `%s` for the table name as type `regclass` in `format()`:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

Related:

- [Count NULL values per row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205887/count-null-values-per-row/205899#205899)

Comment: Big big thanks! This kind of answer is of public interest!

Comment: Impressive answer (as usual). I'm just wondering if it might be worth mentioning to the OP that one **can** set stats on a column by column basis. Delving into the source code is (currently) above my pay grade, but I'm just wondering that **if** there are columns that the OP may be more or less interested in, setting stats on a col-by-col basis might be less onerous than on a table-wide one? I found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html) and  [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html) helpful.

Comment: @Vérace: Increasing the statistics target with `SET STATISTICS` can be done per column. Yes, may be of relevance. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034896/939860 But that's just a gradual improvement for estimates in `pg_stats` (that comes at a price). BTW, you posted the same link twice. A typo, I assume.

Comment: Yes, sorry, 2nd link was meant to be [ALTER TABLE...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) - `SET STATISTICS...`, leads on to section [14.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html) which leads to an entire [chapter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats-details.html). I hope you don't mind me having the temerity to suggest this, but you, it appears to me, want your answers to cover all the bases, so I thought it might be a useful point to note? In any case, keep up the good work - many of your posts are nothing short of awe-inspiring!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you are a god amongst men!  Managed to follow f_null_ratio (eventually), but may I ask - why %s rather than %L in the subquery within the dynamic SQL string?  I'm trying to modify this to a) get these stats for all tables in a given schema, b) consider empty strings as NULLs for text fields and c) exclude the table-level stats rows you're generating.

Comment: @enjayaitch: There is a link to a detailed explanation for the use `%s`. I declared it more clearly now. And I made the output of table stats optional. Consider the updated version. Good luck with the rest!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you!  Glad to report I was able to do the empty string addition and have also added another column for the maximum length of strings.  Then I just use that in a lateral join within another SQL function to do the whole schema.  Always worth learning something new even if it takes longer than the dumb way the first time.