# Count missing values in each column of the table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, null

Question: Which column of `fortune500` (a table) has the most missing values? To find out, I have checked each column individually mentioned below, which is very tedious.

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ticker IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ticker_null_num, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN profits_change IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS profits_change_null_num,
    SUM(CASE WHEN industry IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS industry_null_num
FROM fortune500;
```

And also performed the following query for each column individually:

```sql
SELECT count(*) - count(ticker) AS missing
  FROM fortune500;
 etc....
```

**My Question:**
Is there any better/dynamic way of doing it because this approach is very cumbersome and it will take a lot of time as I have like 50 - 60 columns in a table then what should I do in that case instead of this manual approach. Can somebody help me find the missing values of each column sorted in a descending order with a good method? Like for example:

```
COLUMN_NAME    MISSING_VALUES_COUNT
col1               60
col2               50
col3               45
col4               40
etc.....
```

Comment: Do you know there is a table or view containing the column names (and more) of each table or view in the DB? Also, when you analyze a table, PostgreSQL stores an estimate of what you're asking.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Couldn't get you. Can you be more precise? Is this a right platform to ask or I should ask this on stack overflow instead?

Comment: Do it in 2 steps. First use information_schema.columns to generate your query, execute your query. For your second question, calculate count(*) once and use the result

Comment: Why do you mind that it is "tedious" and "cumbersome"?  You have to write it only once.  I'd like to know to what use you need this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the rows into JSON to dynamically generate one row for each column:

```
select colname, 
       count(cols.value) as non_null_values,
       (select count(*) from the_table) - count(cols.value) as missing
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each(jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t))) as cols(colname, value)
group by colname;
```

But this isn't going to be fast on large tables.

Comment: If you define "the_table" as a CTE,  2 minutes for 7 million rows of 7 columns.  A beautiful solution, wish I knew what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

A query of this basic form only uses a **single sequential scan** and is as efficient as it gets:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
        , count(ticker) AS ticker
        , count(profits_change) AS profits_change
        , count(industry) AS industry
     -- , more?
   FROM   fortune500
   ) t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES
      ('ticker', ct - ticker)
    , ('profits_change', ct - profits_change)
    , ('industry', ct - industry
 -- , more?
   ) x(column_name, missing_values)
   ORDER  BY missing_values DESC, column_name DESC;
```

This function generates and executes the query for all columns of a given table dynamically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_count_nulls(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (column_name text, missing_values bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   SELECT format(
   $$
   SELECT x.*
   FROM  (SELECT count(*) AS ct, %s FROM %s) t
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (VALUES %s) x(col, nulls)
   ORDER  BY nulls DESC, col DESC
   $$, string_agg(format('count(%1$I) AS %1$I', attname), ', ')
     , $1
     , string_agg(format('(%1$L, ct - %1$I)', attname), ', ')
      )
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = $1
   AND    attnum > 0
   AND    NOT attisdropped
   -- more filters?
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_count_nulls('public.fortune500');  -- optionally schema-qualified
```

Produces the requested result.
All identifiers are handled safely (quoted when required, no SQL injection).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=23c2c6e718e513cbcbafddc2dc8c3df9)*

Related:

- [How do I list all columns for a specified table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table/22420#22420)
- [psql: SELECT * ... except one column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114760/psql-select-except-one-column/115315#115315)
- [Count NULL values per row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205887/count-null-values-per-row/205899#205899)

Comment: I'm trying to partition the data from the first query, where exactly should I use `group by` and where should I add the values I'm grouping for. For now, I created a view and ran it for every instance of it, but it seems that this should work. (Suppose that the column is year_transfer)

Comment: @Braiam: Please ask your question as new question. Doesn't fit into a comment. You can always link to this Q or A for reference. And you can drop a comment here to link back / get my attention.